# Problem in using pg_trgm PostgreSQL - function similarity(tsvector, unknown) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, trigram

I am using PostgreSQL for FTS features. I am working on partial word search and I want to use trigram based matching.

I have executed following queries.

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm SCHEMA schema_name;
SELECT SIMILARITY ('Sensor Values', 'sensor');
```

Error message:

```
ERROR:  function similarity(unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SIMILARITY ('Sensor Values', 'sensor');
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 8
```

I am not sure how I can solve mentioned error. I am using PostgreSQL 14.5 and PG ADMIN 4 (6.12) on windows machine.

Do I need to set some path to use all Tri gram functions?

Comment: It looks like you put the extension's objects into a schema not in your search_path.  Either change your search_path, or change where you put the objects.

Comment: The error message in your title and the one in your body text are different..

Comment: Does it work with a cast? `SELECT SIMILARITY ('Sensor Values'::text, 'sensor'::text);`

Comment: Hello all, Thanks for the inputs. by executing "SET search_path = schema_name;" and adding extensions (adminpack + pipgdql) it worked.